# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _C: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: python, pytorch, forecasting, facebook-prophet

----> 1 from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet
2 from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error, mean_squared_error
3
4 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import ForecastConfig
5 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import MetadataParam

c:\users\anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\neuralprophet_*init*_.py in 
17 log.addHandler(f_handler)
18
---> 19 from .forecaster import NeuralProphet
20 from .utils import set_random_seed

c:\users\anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\neuralprophet\forecaster.py in 
4 import numpy as np
5 import pandas as pd
----> 6 import torch
7 from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
8 from torch import optim

c:\users\anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\torch_*init*_.py in 
95 del _dl_flags
96
---> 97 from torch._C import *
98
99 **all** += [name for name in dir(_C)

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _C: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

please help

Comment: One probable reason that imports are failing is because your system doesn't hav "enough memory" (enough RAM). You can verify by checking your system's available RAM space

Comment: Thanks issue resolved

Comment: @snehalvirwadekar how did you solve it...

Comment: @HassanKanso i upgraded RAM and it worked